# Im trying to submit a form, but no data comes out of it

Tags: php, forms

Im trying to submit a form, and i have done this so many times before i and i do not understand why this single form does not want to work, my other forms do work perfectly, but i have no idea why this particuler form does not want to.

I have tried running a: print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); but this is all i get: Array ( ) Array ( )

```
<form name="myForm" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <div class="id-input">ID:</div>
        <label class="input2 red bold">
            <?php if(isset($sli_u_id)) echo($sli_u_id);?>
        </label>

     <input class="input" name="sli_title" value="<?php if(isset($sli_u_title)) echo($sli_u_title);?>" placeholder="Title">

    <div class="button-area">
        <input class="btn-upload" type="file" name="sli_img">
        <div class="btn-upload-true">Vælg fil</div>
        <div id="file_name">img/sliders/<?php if(isset($sli_u_img)) echo($sli_u_img);?></div>
    </div>

    <input class="btn" name="sli_submit" type="submit" value="<?php if ($mode == 'update') echo 'Opdater'; elseif ($mode == 'insert') echo 'Opret'; ?>">
    <a href="panel.php?page=sliderimage.php">
        <button class="danger-btn" type="button" href="">Annuller</button>
    </a>

<input type="hidden" name="sli_id" value="<?php if(isset($sli_u_id)) echo($sli_u_id);?>">
</form>
```

Both pages:

http://pastebin.com/L9CBKik6

[http://pastebin.com/XC3tzkhy](http://pastebin.com/L9CBKik6)

Comment: it should work, did you check out in firebug or chrome if it sends anything or not

Comment: Please provide your PHP.

Comment: @EternalHour Links added.

Comment: Do you have error_reporting turned on, or have you checked your logs?

Comment: why is your `<form action=""` empty ?

Comment: @dan08 no errors no logs.

Comment: @caramba beacuse everything is on the same page...

Comment: @athax if it's on the same page remove the action attribute entirely. You don't need it. That might be the reason it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound [pedantic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pedantry), but have you done it?

Break the problem into pieces and find out exactly where the problem is.

Begin with only one element in the form. Submit it, and see what happens. If it doesn't work, fix it - then add one more element. No more than that.

Then add the next element -- until you find / fix all the problems.

It may sound like a lot of work, but you've been working on this for an hour. By the above method, you should find the solution in less than 15 mins.

Comment: +1, it's interesting how sometimes people just can't see a way to break things apart when they're overwhelmed. Happens to me all the time

Comment: Also guilty - it's [how I know](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew+7%3A5&version=NLT). <== referring to myself

Comment: @gibberish didn't you want to say: "By the above method, you should find the `solution` in less than 15mins."

Comment: Im currently breaking it down, for some reason only this form screws me up D: i rewrote it three times.

Comment: @Athax The *divide and conquer* method almost always works -- but it's tedious and a pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Athax your problem appear to be a header('location: ..8'); and a die(); you used, you don't need it since you are on the same page, you included your file.